# How to convert mongodb array of object to array of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb with mongoose in NodeJs project.

I want to convert my data array of object to array of string like

```
[
  {
    id: '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  },
  {
    id: '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  },
  {
    id: '638de425cbb676123ad20509',
  },
  {
    id: '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  },
  {
    id: '638dc4cc48b1de03d0d920b7',
  },
  {
    id: '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  },
  {
    id: '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  },
];
```

**Convert to**

```
 ['6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  '638de425cbb676123ad20509',
  '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  '638dc4cc48b1de03d0d920b7',
  '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433']
```

How I convert my data using mongodb not JavaScript method like, map, filter, find etc

I did not convert the data because lack of mongodb knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this directly within mongodb. The reason is that a document must be an object. Eg, you cannot replace the object with a string. Instead, you have 3 options:

1 - Get the output very close, but you just have to locate the array: https://mongoplayground.net/p/furNa_ezJ5l

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT.id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Gives you:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "data": [
      "6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433",
      "638de425cbb676123ad204f6",
      "638de425cbb676123ad20509",
      "6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433",
      "638dc4cc48b1de03d0d920b7",
      "638de425cbb676123ad204f6",
      "6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433"
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the data you want will be:
`const stringArray = result[0].data`

2 - Use JS after your query

```
db.collection.find({}).toArray().map( function(u) { return u.id } )
```

3 - Magic distinct values

Assuming that your values of `id` are always unique and that you don't want to do any further querying or aggregation, you can ask mongo for the unique ones:

```
db.collection.distinct('id')
```

Which should give you:

```
 ['6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  '638de425cbb676123ad20509',
  '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433',
  '638dc4cc48b1de03d0d920b7',
  '638de425cbb676123ad204f6',
  '6375ce97e8ec382b8dbf8433']
```